# Gensim Word2Vec Error: ValueError: missing section header before line #0

Tags: python, html, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am new to Gensim Word2Vec. I was trying to use Word2Vec to build word vectors for some raw html files. So I first convert the html file into txt file.

#### My First Question:

When I train the word2vec model, everything is fine. But when I want to test the accuracy of the model by doing

```
model.accuracy(file_name)
```

it produced error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_w2v.py", line 82, in <module>
    main()
  File "build_w2v.py", line 77, in main
    gen_w2v_model()
  File "build_w2v.py", line 71, in gen_w2v_model
    accuracy = model.accuracy(target)
  File "/home/k/shankai/app/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1330, in accuracy
    return self.wv.accuracy(questions, restrict_vocab, most_similar, case_insensitive)
  File "/home/k/shankai/app/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 679, in accuracy
    raise ValueError("missing section header before line #%i in %s" % (line_no, questions))
ValueError: missing section header before line #0
```

Below is the sample file:

```
zGR='ca-about-health_js';var ziRfw=0;zobt=" Vision Ads";zOBT=" Ads";function zIpSS(u){zpu(0,u,280,375,"ssWin")}function zIlb(l,t,f){zT(l,'18/1Pp/wX')}


zWASL=1;zGRH=1
#rs{margin:0 0 10px}#rs #n5{font-weight:bold}#rs a{padding:7px;text-transform:capitalize}Poking Eyelashes - Poking Eyelashes Problem


<!--
zGOW=0;xd=0;zap="";zAth='25752';zAthG='25752';zTt='11';zir='';zBTS=0;zBT=0;zSt='';zGz=''
ch='health';gs='vision';xg="Vision";zcs=''
zFDT='0'
zFST='0'
zOr='BA15WT26OkWA0O1b';zTbO=zRQO=1;zp0=zp1=zp2=zp3=zfs=0;zDc=1;
zSm=zSu=zhc=zpb=zgs=zdn='';zFS='BA110BA0110B00101';zFD='BA110BA0110B00101'
zDO=zis=1;zpid=zi=zRf=ztp=zpo=0;zdx=20;zfx=100;zJs=0;
zi=1;zz=';336280=2-1-1299;72890=2-1-1299;336155=2-1-12-1;93048=2-1-12-1;30050=2-1-12-1';zx='100';zde=15;zdp=1440;zds=1440;zfp=0;zfs=66;zfd=100;zdd=20;zaX=new Array(11, new Array(100,1051,8192,2,'336,300'),7, new Array(100,284,8196,12,'336,400'));zDc=1;;zDO=1;;zD336=1;zhc='';;zGTH=1;
zGo=0;zG=17;zTac=2;zDot=0;
zObT="Vision";zRad=5;var tp=" primedia_"+(zBT?"":"non_")+"site_targeting";if(!this.zGCID)zGCID=tp
else zGCID+=tp;
if(zBT>0){zOBR=1}
if(!this.uy)uy='about.com';if(typeof document.domain!="undefined")document.domain=uy;//-->


function zob(p){if(!this.zOfs)return;var a=zOfs,t,i=0,l=a.length;if(l){w('<div id="oF"><b>'+(this.zobt?zobt:xg+' Ads')+'</b><ul>');while((i<l)&&i<zRad){t=a[i++].line1;w('<li><a href="/z/js/o'+(p?p:'')+'.htm?k='+zUriS(t.toLowerCase())+(this.zobr?zobr:'')+'&d='+zUriS(t)+'&r='+zUriS(zWl)+'" target="_'+(this.zOBNW?'new'+zr(9999):'top')+'">'+t+'</a></li>');}w('</ul></div>')}}function rb600(){if(gEI('bb'))gEI('bb').height=600}zJs=10
zJs=11
zJs=12
zJs=13
zc(5,'jsc',zJs,9999999,'')
zDO=0
```

So This file actually begins with many (I don't know) space or \n. When I open in the vim.[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOz4T.png).

**So what is the problem here?**

#### My second question:

Also, I am doing text classification of some biomedical papers. The files I was given are all raw html files in either Japanese or English. After I do the ascii conversion and some stop_words cleaning, there are still many HTML code left in the file.

When I try to clean these files and restrict the characters to [a-zA-Z0-9], I found some medical terms like [4protein...] or something get not properly cleaned as well.

**Are there any suggestions in how to clean up these files?**

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you applying gensim to minified js files?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is minified js files. These files are produced by another team, and I originally have .html files but then someone in my group convert those into .txt files.

Comment: Unreadable html is said to be minified.

Comment: Ok, I think this file was originally in Japanese, and get ascii converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `accuracy()` should be a set of analogies to test the model against, in the format of the `questions-words.txt` file available from the original word2vec.c distribution. (It should *not* be your own file.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you download this file, you use library
So that's not real txt file.
you have to download real raw txt file!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33901438)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).